# Firebase fetch data using .value observer is not working?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wan't to fetch my firebase data using .value observer, i have an object class named "object" and its has only 1 property named "test" of type string .

Update : my object class

```
public class object : NSObject{

    var test  : String!

}
```

this is my code :

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var ref : FIRDatabaseReference!
    var objarray = [object]()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("root")
        loaddata()
    }

    func loaddata(){

        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let obj = object()
            if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]{
                obj.setValuesForKeys(data)
                self.objarray.append(obj)
                print("%%%%%%% \(obj.test)")
            }

        })

    }

}
```

when i use the .value observer its just retrieve nothing !!, but if i use .childAdded the data will be retrieved ??

could some one guide me if i'm doing something wrong ?

update : [image]Adding firebase database image

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your database in FireBase?

Comment: i added the screenshot

Comment: Not clear what `object` means... could you please add this class definition to your question as well? Thanks!

Comment: object class is added as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looping over the returned dictionary `[String : AnyObject]` and *then* creating the the corresponding `object` instances.

```
ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
        for objectData in data.values {
            let obj = object()
            obj.setValuesForKeys(objectData as! [String : AnyObject])
            self.objarray.append(obj)
            print("%%%%%%% \(obj.test)")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man, i was missing the returned dictionary in the .value observer , now its all work

Comment: one more thing plz , how can i get the key of  my objects ??

Comment: Use `for (key, objectData) in data` instead.